# Office 365, delete Outlook 2016 categories

Tags: microsoft-office

After importing contacts from gmail to outlook, I have a whole bunch of categories I cannot seem to delete. Screenshot from Outlook 2016 for Mac. On the outlook.office365.com I cannot even find these categories.

[image]

Some I want to keep, but most I want to delete, except that I have no idea how to get rid of any of them. These categories are in my calendar, contacts, tasks... They are not in my list of categories, either.

[image]

Anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hours of frustrated research, the only fix I found is to create a new category with the EXACT same name as the unwanted category. This assigns the unwanted category a color, and you can then delete it. Not sure how technical of a fix this is, but it will get unwanted categories out of your navigation pane. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to do same as MS created a load of categories from nowhere.

I found if you open the dropdown list of categories, click on all categories near the bottom of the dropdown list, it opens a box where you can see all the categories.

Simply tick the box next to the ones you don't want, then click *Delete*. It will ask if you are sure blah blah. Click *Yes*.

They seem to have now gone from the dropdown list, hopefully permanently.